# 2d graph in real-time by using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a really basic question in opencv and c++. I am trying to graph something in real time by using opencv. I am looking to find a function to draw a graph in rel-time. But still unssuccesful.
I need a function that gets two arrays as an input one for x axis and one for y. I tried with this but seems not work in real-time http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html

I just need to know if there is something available in opencv or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provides just [low level drawing primitives](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html), so you have to look for other libraries to plot chars, or create the code yourself.